# Using CSS Sprites as Buttons & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-sprites

my partner gave me a job to do because he wants me to learn jQuery. I'm making a section of our landing page that has three buttons that replace the content for each button. I've got that down (at least the basic function) but I need some help getting the sprites to toggle on when clicked and also toggle off when another button is clicked.

I'd like the first button to be on its active state (class .des1activecontent) when the page initially loads, and to switch when the other buttons are clicked.

Here is the jsfiddle of my most recent attempt at getting the buttons to style correctly. Having trouble with class selectors.

NOTE: Look at the jsfiddles please, I only posted this from it because it's required for me to post this.

```
$('#linkwrapper div a').on('click', function(){
    var lmb = this+"activecontent";
    $('#linkwrapper div a').removeClass(lmb);
    $(this).addClass(lmb);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/86/

And here is the jsfiddle of the whole plugin so you can have a better understanding of what I'm doing. Thanks again in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/89F9H/

Comment: jsfiddle can't work with localhost urls

Comment: only if we could see the images....

Comment: `this` in your code sample refers to the entire `a` DOM element, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: lol whoops totally forgot i was working on localhost. ill update soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple classes to any DOM element, and style them in CSS:

```
.des3.activecontent {
    background-position: 0 -375px;
}
.des1.activecontent {
    background-position: 0 -250px;
}
.des2.activecontent {
    background-position: 0 -625px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#linkwrapper div a').on('click', function () {
    var lmb = "activecontent";
    $('#linkwrapper div a').removeClass(lmb);
    $(this).addClass(lmb);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HTHnW/87/

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Thanks for cleaning up some of my messy code too. Still learning the development side of design!